# How do I find the least possible number of edges in graph?

Tags: graph-theory

Let n be an integer such that n ≥ 4. What is the least possible number of edges in graph
with n vertices in which each edge is in at least two different cycles? Give your answer as
an expression in terms of n.

I've tried drawing out graph with 4,5 and 6 vertices and found out that the min edge is just n + 1 but I am not sure if my answer is correct. My current answer is n + 1 = e where n is number of vertices and e is number of edges.

Comment: Is there a requirement that each vertex must have at least one edge? Otherwise just 5  edges work.

Comment: I think I have to give the answer as an expression, so not a number

Comment: A number is an expression all right. Then again, having assumed the said requirement, your answer looks good to me.

Comment: yes, my bad i meant it in terms of n